# Fetch from Chalice API

Tags: reactjs, post, fetch, chalice

I have an endpoint to add items to a "MasterList" dynamoDB table

[image]

```js
    @app.route('/save_listing', methods=['POST'], content_types=['application/json'], cors=cors_config)
    def post_item():
        try:
            data = app.current_request.json_body
        except Exception as e:
            data = e
        try:
            insert_item({ 
                'pk': data['sku'],
                "account" : data['account']
            })
        except Exception as e:
            return str(e)
        return str(data)
```

When I POST using postman, It adds to the table, and returns the data string.

[image]

Now I am trying to implement the same POST in ReactJS

```js
    createListing(listing) {
        console.log(listing)
        fetch('https://z3sr9ja4zf.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api/save_listing', {
          method: 'post',
          body: JSON.stringify(listing)

        }).then(function(response) {
          return response;
        });
    }
```

console.log(listing) produces

[image]

How can I use the endpoint on ReactJS, it seems like I am not passing the object correctly. Right now nothing is writing to the DB, and I get a Undefined response. Also I have gottne 415 response.

Thank you in advance.

`JSON.stringify(listing)` produces:

{"sku":"OX-PFWI-BNV0","account":"AO","asin":"","cogl":-5.09,"cogs":0,"status":"","launch_date":"NULL","per_item_on_hand_rate":0,"selling_price":0,"expected_fulfillment_fee_per_unit":0,"rating":0,"picture_count":0,"amz_status":"","fba_fee":0,"item_volume":"NULL","product_size_tier":"","volume_rate":"NULL","country":"USA","manager":"NULL","sub_category":"NULL"}

If I post using postman:

[image]

And the Headers:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The response code [HTTP 415](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/415) is indicating that the server doesn't like the format of your payload. Try modifying your code to include the same headers as what you have in your PostMan request:

```
createListing(listing) {
    console.log(listing)
    fetch('https://z3sr9ja4zf.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/api/save_listing', {
      method: 'post',
      headers: {
         Accept: 'application/json',
         'Content-Type': 'application/json',
     },
      body: JSON.stringify(listing)

    }).then(function(response) {
      return response;
    });
}
```

**NOTE:** I didn't include `Accept-Encoding` in this code snippet as the value in your screenshot isn't valid - see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding) for more information.